# Selecting column by string in Google App Engine NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have an entity in Google App Engine as below:

```
class HesapKalemi(ndb.Model):
hk=ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
ha=ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
A=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
B=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
C=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
F=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
G=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
H=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
I=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
J=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
DG=ndb.FloatProperty(default=0.00)
```

As known, the normal query can be below:

```
sektorkodu=self.request.get('sektorkodu')
    qall=HesapKalemi.query().order(HesapKalemi.hk)
    for hesap in qall:
        hesap.ho=hesap.A
```

Is there any way to fetching A column by writing this way:

```
hesap.GETTHECOLUMN('A') or
hesap.GETTHECOLUMN(sektorkodu)
```

I have a very horizontal table and want to query it without if-else structure by the .GETTHECOLUMN('string') method.

Is there this kind of method?

Answer (score 3):

In the NDB world, this is called [Projection, or a Projection Query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries). In that link to the docs, you'll see the following:

> Projection queries are similar to SQL queries of the form:
>
> ```
> SELECT name, email, phone FROM CUSTOMER
> ```

So the `.GETTHECOLUMN('A')`  method you're after would look like either of these:

```
qall_option_one = HesapKalemi.query().order(HesapKalemi.hk).fetch(projection=['A'])
qall_option_two = HesapKalemi.query().order(HesapKalemi.hk).fetch(projection=[HasepKalemi.A])

# to access the values
for hesap in qall_option_one:
    print hesap

# output:
# HesapKalemi(key=Key('HesapKalemi', 1234567890), A=0.00, _projection=('A',))
# HesapKalemi(key=Key('HesapKalemi', 1234567891), A=0.00, _projection=('A',))
# ...
```

This is a bit faster than getting the full entities with all of their properties, but you do still have to iterate through them afterwards, even if you want to just generate a list of the 'A' values. Another option you should look at is ["Calling a Function For Each Entity (Mapping)"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#map), where you define a callback function to be called on each entity as the query runs. So let's say you just want a list of the 'A' values. You could form that list like this:

```
def callback(hesap):
    return hesap.A

a_values = HesapKelami.query().map(callback)
# a_values = [0.00, 0.00, ...]
```

If you're really after performance, look into [asynchronous gets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async#using).

Note: instead of projection, you could use [GQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference), but that would look messier/more confusing than using projection with the regular ndb Query syntax IMO.

Edit: To answer your question in your comment, you can use either projection or mapping to select data from multiple properties.

Projection of multiple properties:

```
qall_option_one = HesapKalemi.query().order(HesapKalemi.hk).fetch(projection=['A', 'B', 'C'])
qall_option_two = HesapKalemi.query().order(HesapKalemi.hk).fetch(projection=[HesapKalemi.A, HesapKalemi.B, HesapKalemi.C])
# to access the values
for hesap in qall_option_one:
    print hesap

# output:
# HesapKalemi(key=Key('HesapKalemi', 1234567890), A=0.00, B=0.00, C=0.00 _projection=('A', 'B', 'C',))
# HesapKalemi(key=Key('HesapKalemi', 1234567891), A=0.00, B=0.00, C=0.00 _projection=('A', 'B', 'C',))
# ...
```

Mapping to return multiple properties:

```
def callback(hesap):
    # this returns a tuple of A,B,C values
    return hesap.A, hesap.B, hesap.C

values = HesapKelami.query().map(callback)
# values is a list of tuples
# values = [(0.00, 0.00, 0.00), (0.00, 0.00, 0.00), ...]
```

Edit #2: After rereading the question and comments, I think your question, or at least part of it, may be how to get the property from the model itself using a string, and not how to pull one column out of the datastore. To answer that question, use `getattr(hesap, "property_name")`, or, and this may be more suited to your needs, turn hesap into a dict with `hesap_dict = hesap.to_dict()`. Then you could do this:

```
property_name = 'some_string'
hesap = HesapKelami.query().fetch(1)[0]
hesap_dict = hesap.to_dict()
property_value = hesap_dict.get(property_name, None)
```

You could pass `hesap_dict` to your Jinja2 template, and then I think you could accomplish what you asked about in your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Can we use projection feature for more than one columns?

Comment: Yes, you can use projection for multiple columns. You can also map a function to return tuples/lists/dicts containing values of multiple columns. I will edit the answer to include examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what about calling from Jinja template. Is there any way for renaming the entity dynamic column name (like A,B,C) to standard name like DYNAMICCOLUMNNAME to call in Jinja {{hesap.DYNAMICCOLUMNNAME}}

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you could return a dict from the callback function instead of a tuple, where the dict would look something like `{"column_name_one": hesap.A, "column_name_two": hesap.B, "column_name_three": hesap.C}` and then, in your Jinja2 template, iterate through the list of those dicts? I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can probably find what you need by researching Jinja in further detail. If not, you may be best served asking a new question about Jinja.

Comment: The problem is the column name A, B... C is flexible according to the parameter comes from URL. Therefore, I can not map it by the callback. Is there way of calling the hesap.A as hesap."A" or hesap.FUNC("colunmnname"). 
I am sorry for proloning the comments.

Comment: If you use projection, then yes, you can use strings to specify the property name (look at `qall_option_one` provided in my examples). If you use mapping, you could use a lambda function as the callback like so: `values = HesapKelami.query().map(lambda h: getattr(h, column_name_string))`, and `column_name_string` can then be a string taken from your url.